# History of powers beyond squares and cubes

Tags: ho.history-overview

The ancient Babylonians understood squares:

---

[image]

<sup>[Plimpton 322](http://www.aliraqi.org/forums/showthread.php?p=147847980)</sup>

---

The ancient Athenians understood cubes, if we can take
doubling the cube, i.e., [the Delian problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeDuplication.html), as evidence.

My question is:

> **Q**. When were 4th, 5th, $\ldots$, $n$-th powers contemplated/understood/used?

I am wondering how tied was the understanding of powers/exponentiation
to geometry, to spatial dimensions. Did the ancients generalize their
explorations to arbitrary integer exponents?

Comment: In geometry, you  might look at the history of curves like the parabola, cycloids and variations, tractrix, and so on.  If they had any geometric understanding of higher exponents, it would most likely be through such curves.

Comment: I am not a historian, but if the people from early millenia had any concept of four or higher dimensions, I suspect it would be a near-theological conception more than an algebraic or geometric conception.

Comment: I read somewhere (maybe someone has a reference) that in the classical Greek geometry powers 4 and up never appear.  Second power is area, third power is volume, and geometry is a theory to describe the real world, so higher powers are nonsense.  Or something to that effect.

Comment: Maybe this is a bit naive, but after all the Babylonians you mention did use a positional numeral system with base 60. When they ever needed a number larger then 215,999, they will have implicitly used cubes. (And fourth powers if they had to count until 12,960,000.)

Comment: Good point, Moritz!

Comment: Have you checked A History of Greek Mathematics by Thomas Heath online?

Comment: Not a fourth power but a product of four factors occurs in Heron's formula for the area of a triangle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Wikipedia's article on the Mother Goose rhyme "As I was going to St. Ives"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_I_was_going_to_St_Ives) suggests that curiosity about higher powers has existed a long time.

The Rhind Mathematical Papyrus (Problem 79), dated to around 1650 BC, could be described with the following text:

> There are seven houses;
> In each house there are seven cats;
> Each cat catches seven mice;
> Each mouse would have eaten seven ears of corn;
> If sown, each ear of corn would have produced seven hekat of grain.
> How many things are mentioned altogether?

**Edit:** Interestingly, the $7^5$ hekat of grain here are *counterfactual* (imagined, not actually existing); as is perhaps the very notion of a number like $7^5$, to the author of the papyrus.

Comment: That is a nice example of repeating an operation; it would also be interesting, when powers were perceived as "the next" operation in the sequence of addition as repeated increments by 1 and, multiplication as repeated additions of the same number.

Comment: $7^5$---Nice catch!

Comment: This may not be the definitive answer, but it is quite suggestive and informative. And so I accept it. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great question and a great answer, although I wonder if there's a better translation for "ear of corn" which, presumably, were unknown to the ancient Egyptians. I've heard "grain of barley..."

Answer (score 18):

The cuneiform tablet [MS 2351](http://www.schoyencollection.com/mathematics-collection/arithmetics/ms-2351) from the 19th century BC contains the 15-digit sexagesimal number 13 22 50 54 59 09 29 58 26 43 17 31 51 06 40, which happens to equal $20^{20}$. I also seem to remember they constructed a table of reciprocals for numbers of the form $125 \cdot 2^n$ for exponents up to $19$.

Edit. Last year some fragments of a large table have been identified:
[Ossendrijver](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1306/1306.5989.pdf) discovered that the complete table contained the powers of 9 up to $9^{46}$.

Comment: That's amazing! And in *A Remarkable Collection of Babylonian Mathematical Texts* by Jöran Friberg I read that tablet MS 2205 gives $20^{12}$ and $20^{16}$. Friberg thinks these numbers may represent exercises in computing square roots, although to some extent of course that remains guesswork.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the tablet containing the list of powers of $9$ is of Late Babylonian origin (which is the era from approx. 400 BC to 100 BC). In this era we also encounter mathematicians like Euclid, who of course uses powers implicitly throughout the *Elements* (just think of the summing of the geometric series).

Comment: So they were just one step away from the Cunningham Project, https://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun/intro

Comment: @Gerry: Not really. They used factorization techniques for computing square roots and reciprocals, but only regular factors (those dividing powers of 60). There are a couple of examples of division with remainder by 7, 11 or 13, but no prime factorizations involving primes $> 5$.

Answer (score 17):

The first definition of the powers beyond the third is probably in Diophantus' *Arithmetica* (written somewhere from 100 BC to 300 AD).

In the introduction to that work, he defines fourth powers (δυναμοδύναμεις "dynamodynameis", lit. "square-squares"), fifth powers (δυναμόκυβοι "dynamokuboi", lit. "square-cubes"), and sixth powers (κυβόκυβοι "kubokuboi", lit. "cube-cubes"). Throughout the course of the work, he uses all of these powers. Moreover, he assigns them no geometrical significance whatsoever, just as he doesn't think of squares and cubes themselves in a geometric way; e.g., he sees no problem in adding the square of the unknown to a constant, etc.

**Edit:** After writing the above, I checked up on Sir Thomas Heath's great treatise on Diophantus. Apparently, Heron used the same term for the fourth power as Diophantus. Since Diophantus' dates are somewhat uncertain, he may or may not have been anticipated by Heron.

A screenshot from Heath's book:

[image: Diophantus' definition of the first few powers]

Answer (score 12):

Just for the record, I thought this passage from [Omar Khayyam's algebra book](https://archive.org/details/AnEssayByTheUniquelyWiseabelFathOmarBinAl-khayyamOnAlgebraAnd) (p.49) should be here. In particular, it shows how hard it was to to tie  the understanding of powers to geometry

> I say: what algebraists call square-square is an imaginary concept in
>   continuous quantities. It has no existence in any way in materialistic
>   objects. For continuous quantities, the terms square-square,
>   square-cube and cube-cube are used to denote the number (coefficient)
>   of the object (variable)... The things that algebraists use to denote objects and quantities are:
>   number, root, square and cube. The number has to be taken as an
>   abstract concept. It has no existence unless it is individuated by
>   things...
>   Square-square, which, to the algebraists, is the product of the square
>   by itself, has no meaning in continuous objects. This is because how
>   can one multiply a square, which is a surface, by itself? Since the
>   square is a two-dimensional object (geometrical figure), and
>   two-dimensional by two-dimensional is a four dimensional object. But
>   solids cannot have more than three dimensions. All objects in algebra
>   are generated from these four genera. And anyone who says that algebra
>   is a trick to determine unknown numbers is wrong. So don’t pay
>   attention to these people. It is true that algebra and equations are
>   geometrical things...

**Edit.** René's post and Joël's comment gave me some new insight about Khayyam's understanding of powers higher than three. Of course, he was aware of them as he explains how a certain equation of power 4 can be solved:

> Now, whoever said: square-square plus three squares equals
>   twenty-eight; he halved the squares then multiplied it by itself and
>   then added the number; and took the root of the result to equal five
>   and a half; then subtracted half the squares to get four which the
>   square, and the square of the square is sixteen...

But, for him algebra and equations were attached to geometry. Apart from number that "has to be taken as an abstract concept", $x$ , $x^2$, and $x^3$ had  geometrical meaning, side, square , and cube, respectively. Thus, immediately after mentioning the solution of the equation above, he warns the reader as follows:

> ...and he thought that he deduced the square of the square using
>   algebra: **is very feeble in his thinking**. This is because he did not
>   deduce the square of the square but rather he deduced the square.It is exactly as if he said: square plus three roots equals twenty-eight, then he determined the root using the second reduction, and concluded that the square of this root is the square of the square, which is a secret from which you will come to know other secrets.

All in all, it is a good example of how a "philosophical" belief could impede the advance of knowledge even for such an intelligent mind.

Comment: Interesting. Especially in comparison with René's post, which shows that Diophantus' point of view is closer to the modern one.

Comment: Indeed interesting. It is intriguing to see how long it took even the greatest minds to treat algebra as independent of geometry. Even in as late a mathematician as François Viète (late 16th century), we find a very determined attempt to reconcile a sophisticated algebraic theory with a "dimensionalized" number system. I guess that, for a long time, what we call the number line was the most powerful source for producing numbers, and then of course the numbers did come with their own specific dimension.

Comment: I do not necessarily agree with the concluding sentence of this answer nor with the comment of @Joël. Instead, Khayyam's intelligence led him to pose and to seriously ponder an extremely important mathematical/geometric question which is quite close to issues we discuss in modern geometry and topology: What is the product of a surface with itself? It is rather ahistorical to suggest that his philosophical beliefs impeded the solution. What future historians might laugh at our "philosophical" inability to solve the P=NP conjecture?

Comment: I think we must not dismiss beforehand the possibility that philosophical beliefs can stand in the way of mathematical progress. It is also not really a forceful argument that Khayyam's way of thinking somehow lines up with modern-day topology: after all, Khayyam wasn't doing topology, he was doing algebra. But other than that I agree with you: the above does not convince me that Khayyam's meta-mathematical thinking prevented him from making progress that he might "otherwise" have made.

Comment: @René Indeed, my conclusion was not just based on a few paragraphs I mentioned above. It was based on my previous reading of Khayyam. Tying algebra to geometry costed him and progress of mathematics a lot (about five hundred years for the latter).

Comment: @LeeMosher Please see my comment above